# how to make element check code simpler or one-liner in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I wanna make simple condition to check whether element 'a' in A and element 'b' in B has a some characteristic.

the below code operates well, it looks dirty, so, I wanna make it simpler, or one-liner. are there any way to do that?

```
    def check_direction(A, B):
        for a in A:
            for b in B:
                if c_matrix.loc()[a][b]!="->":
                    return False
        return True
```

Comment: You might want to check out the `any` or `all` functions together with generator expressions. Something like `all(c_matrix.loc()[a][b] == '->' for a in A for b in B)` could work.

Comment: Since `c_matrix.loc()` is just a label-based indexer, have you tried *just testing if `->` is present in your frame*?

Comment: Try something like `all(c_matrix.loc()[a][b]=="->" for a in A for b in B)`

Comment: Otherwise, use `return all(c_matrix.loc()[a][b] == "->" for a in A for b in B)`, which produces `True` *only* if all tests pass, and `False` for the first case where the value is not equal to `->`.

Comment: Ok, now that 3 different people have suggested the same thing, this seems to be the solution :)

Comment: thank you a lot!!!!! it is exactly thing I want. Thank you n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the possible pandas or numpy angles that `c_matrix.loc()` suggests might be available, you can use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to get the exact same functionality:

```
return all(c_matrix.loc()[a][b] == "->" for a in A for b in B)
```

`all()` short-circuits; as soon as a `c_matrix.loc()[a][b] == "->"` fails, `False` is returned. `True` is only produced if *all* tests pass.

Answer (score 0):

Here I follow a different approach from [Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters)'s one, he postulated that Numpy/Pandas are not relevant for the answer, I proceed with the understanding that everything is a Numpy array...

First, for demonstrational purposes, we create a matrix of strings, among them the one we don't want in your sample

```
In [37]: toks = ['--', '-+', '+-', '-|', '|-', '->', '<-']
In [38]: matrix = np.array([[toks[np.random.randint(7)] for j in range(5)] for i in range(4)])
In [39]: matrix
Out[39]: 
array([['|-', '--', '<-', '-|', '-|'],
       ['|-', '<-', '--', '+-', '--'],
       ['|-', '-+', '-+', '<-', '-+'],
       ['<-', '->', '->', '-|', '--']],
      dtype='<U2')
```

next, two vector of indices

```
In [40]: A, B = np.array([2,3]), np.array([0,1,4])
```

and the correct broadcasting rule to apply them to indexing `matrix`

```
In [41]: matrix[A[:,None],B]
Out[41]: 
array([['|-', '-+', '-+'],
       ['<-', '->', '--']],
      dtype='<U2')
```

and eventually, similar to what was suggested in comments and proposed in other answers

```
In [42]: np.all(matrix[A[:,None],B] == '->')
Out[42]: False
```

I would like to stress the `matrix[A[:,None],B]` line, that could be commented like this "Look ma', no loops" ;-)

---

In terms of a function definition (more general than yours)

```
def(m, a, b, tok):
    return np.all(m[np.array(a)[:,None], np.array(b)] == tok)
```

note that the function is resilient w/r receiving in `a` and `b` sequences that are not Numpy arrays.

Comment: He didn't say they weren't relevant.  He said ignoring the "possible angles".  That means he is acknowledging there are other relevant answers though he's not going to go into them.